# Special characters sensitive sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a pdo connection to my mysql database (utf8_general_ci) and the connection sets charset to `charset=utf8`:

```
public function connect() {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbName . ';charset=utf8';
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pwd);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
    }
}
```

I got an input fields where users can search for author, title and year:

```
<input class="search-input" name="search" type="text">
```

My php query looks like this:

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE author LIKE ? AND title LIKE ? AND year LIKE ?";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$author_query, $title_query, $date_query]);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The query works fine except that the search query isn't 'special character sensitive'. If the user searches for "m`ü`" (German) or "d`å`" (Danish?), the query will also spit out data that contains "mu" or "da", basically ignoring `ü` and `å` and defaulting it to the base characters. Ideal would be if I only get results that contain `ü` if the user enters `ü`.

Comment: Go look into _collations_. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html

Comment: Think you need a different collation, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122607/which-accented-characters-are-considered-the-same

Comment: show us the create table of your table and see if you have the a collation with support that